# How to do Pagination and sorting by column in JAVA Rest api or graphqlapi with Dynamodb and the request parameters as pagenumber,size,sortby

Tags: rest, sorting, graphql, pagination, amazon-dynamodb

I have only primary key in my table  account id , does sort key is mandatory ?
i tried to query request condition ,but im getting error of wrong condition
this dyamodb pagination is quite different and confusing

```
QueryRequest queryRequest = new QueryRequest()
                .withTableName("customerAccountgridview")
                .withLimit(pageSize)
                .withExclusiveStartKey(exclusiveStartKey != null ? deserializeExclusiveStartKey(exclusiveStartKey) : null)
                .withScanIndexForward(true); // Default to ascending order

if (sortBy != null) {
   queryRequest = queryRequest.withKeyConditionExpression("AccountId = :AccountId")
                                       .withExpressionAttributeNames(Collections.singletonMap("AccountId", sortBy))
                                       .withExpressionAttributeValues(Collections.singletonMap(":sortBy", new AttributeValue().withS(sortBy)));
}

      
QueryResult result = amazonDynamoDB.query(queryRequest);

List<CustomerAccountDetails> customers = result.getItems().stream()
                .map(this::mapToCustomer)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

return customers;
```

Comment: What do you need to know?

Comment: "but im getting error of wrong condition" what error are you getting?